# The difference of any two odd integers is odd?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove: The difference of any two odd integers is odd.

I know you would:

Assume that there a $m=2s+1$, $n=2t+1$ such that $s,t$ are in $E$. $m-n=p$ where $p=2v+1$ such that $v$ is in $E$.

Comment: But the difference is not odd, but even.

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: $5-3=2$ shows difference cannot be odd always. And $(2s+1)-(2t+1)=2(s-t)$ is even, following your set-up, since it is 2 times the integer $s-t$.

Comment: Consider the identities under addition that the only way to get an odd result is: odd+even = odd.  Now, subtract that odd from each side and even=odd-odd.

Comment: ohhhhhhh  thank you! I am a beginner at this at this so it really helps!

Comment: Please. Don’t try to prove anything, especially in elementary number theory, without looking at examples. To repeat: if you have a proposition you’d like to prove, try out the truth of the claim on examples. And not just one.

Answer (score 3):

Like you said, let $m=2s+1, n=2t+1: s,t\in\mathbb{Z}$, then, $m-n=2s+1-2t-1=2(s-t)$. Since $(s-t)\in\mathbb{Z}$, $m-n\in 2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: This really helps as well. I am horrible at this. I know how to start a proof but I have trouble with the middle...